# Issue with Asynchronous State Update in React useReducer when Adding Items to Table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm encountering an issue with asynchronous state updates in React when using
`useReducer` 
and adding items to a table. When I add a new item, it gets added to the state, but with no data initially. The correct data is only displayed after a page refresh.

**I have a useReducer setup with the following reducer:**

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  achats: [],
};

export const AchatsContext = createContext(initialState);

export const achatsReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "SET_ACHATS":
      return {
        achats: payload,
      };
    case "ADD_ACHAT":
      console.log("ADD_ACHAT", state);

      return {
        ...state,
        achats: [payload, ...state.achats],
      };
    case "REMOVE_ACHAT":
      console.log("REMOVE_ACHAT", payload);

      return {
        ...state,
        achats: payload.achats,
      };
    case "UPDATE_ACHAT":
      console.log("UPDATE_ACHAT", payload);

      return {
        ...state,
        achats: payload.achats,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const AchatsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(achatsReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AchatsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AchatsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**And I'm dispatching the ADD_ACHAT action in an async function as follows:**

```
  async function handleSubmit() {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      setMotif(editorRef.current.getContent());
    }

    const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1; // Generates a random number between 1 and 4

    const code = "ACHT-2023-0002";
    const etat = randomValue;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:4000/api/achats/demandes-achats/add`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            date: date,
            motif: motif,
            num_achat: code,
            etat: etat,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_ACHAT", payload: json });
        handleClose();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the error
      console.error("Error:", error);

      // You can access error.response for more details if available
      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Error response:", error.response.data);
      }
    }
  }
```

Despite using await and ensuring that the API call completes successfully, the state seems to be updated asynchronously, leading to the mentioned issue.

I've also checked the reducer and confirmed that it correctly updates the state with the new item. It appears that the UI doesn't reflect the updated state immediately.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue and suggestions for a resolution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever the issue is it seems it's likely not caused by the code you actually shared. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and if possible include an example "http://localhost:4000/api/achats/demandes-achats/add" POST response value that you are trying to update in state. Based on your own admission it sounds like the state is being correctly updated. What, or where, exactly are you seeing *not* updated as expected?

Comment: Hey Here is a gist. Everything work fine except when I add a new item, the ui get updated but in the same time in the console my items array is empty. Unluckely I am using the id from this rendered item to delete it. Hey @drew-reese Here is a gist. Everything work fine except when I add a new item, the ui get updated but in the same time in the console my items array is empty. Unluckely I am using the id from this rendered item to delete it.[ https://gist.github.com/aboubacar-sadik/6735b700df6a49dc2209cb5754632ae5